# Как организовать подписку на LiveData + LoadingState

Tags: android, kotlin, livedata, mvvm-android

Нужно при изменении данных в `БД` оповещать `RecyclerView`. Всё хорошо работает если это напрямую подписка на LiveData. Если добавить в запрос некоторые действия для отображения индикатора загрузки, то всегда возвращается `null` или ошибка типов. Как можно сделать динамическое обновление из `БД` и индикацию?

```
// Dao
@Query("SELECT * FROM share")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Share>>
```

```
// Repository
val fetch = shareDao.getAll()
```

```
// ViewModel
val loadingStateLiveData = MutableLiveData<LoadingState>()

private fun fetch(): LiveData<List<Share>> {
  val liveData = MutableLiveData<List<Share>>()
  loadingStateLiveData.value = LoadingState.LOADING
  viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
      liveData.postValue(repository.fetch)
      loadingStateLiveData .postValue(LoadingState.LOADED)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
  }
  return liveData
}
```

```
// Fragment
viewModel.fetch().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    if (it != null) {
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = homeAdapter
        homeAdapter.updateData(it)
    }
})
```

Строка `liveData.postValue(repository.fetch)` возвращает:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: List<Share>!
Found: LiveData<List<Share>>
```

Если воспользоваться `value` -> `liveData.postValue(repository.fetch.value)` ошибка пропадает, однако, всегда приходит null.

Сделал такой вариант, выполняет то что нужно, однако, не уверен, что технически правильно.

```
    val result: LiveData<List<Share>> = liveData<List<Share>> {
        loadingStateLiveData.value = LoadingState.LOADING
        try {
            val liveData = repository.fetch
            emitSource(liveData)
            loadingStateLiveData.postValue(LoadingState.LOADED)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            loadingStateLiveData.postValue(LoadingState.ERROR)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так, как вариант.

```kotlin
sealed class Response<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Response<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Response<Nothing>()
    object Loading : Response<Nothing>()
}
```

```kotlin
// ViewModel
val data: LiveData<Response<List<Share>>> = loadData()

private fun loadData(): LiveData<Response<List<Share>>> =
   liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
      emit(Response.Loading)

      try {
         emit(repository.fetch)
      } catch (exception: Exception) {
         emit(Response.Error(exception))
      }
   }
```

```kotlin
// View (Fragment)
viewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { response ->
   when (response) {
      is Response.Loading -> {  }
      is Response.Success -> {  }
      is Response.Error -> {  }
   }
})
```

Ошибка возникает потому, что `fetch` у Вас `LiveData<List<Share>>`. Попробуйте в своем примере сделать так:

```kotlin
private fun fetch(): LiveData<List<Share>> {
  val liveData: LiveData<List<String>>
  loadingStateLiveData.value = LoadingState.LOADING
  viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
      liveData = repository.fetch
      loadingStateLiveData .postValue(LoadingState.LOADED)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
  }
  return liveData
}
```

Comment: По вашему примеру следующая ситуация `try { emit(repository.fetch) }` - Required: `Response<List<Share>>` Found: `LiveData<List<Share>>` В Dao у меня так же осталась `LiveData<List<Share>>`. Не могу понять, как нужно преобразовать.

Comment: @NorthFace Dao должен возвращать ```List<Share>```. Репозиторий должен возвращать ```Response<List<Share>>```. То есть в Dao оставляете ```fun getAll(): List<Share>```, в репозитории ```fun getAll(): Response<List<Share>> = Response.Success(shareDao.getAll)``` или ```suspend fun getAll(): Response<List<String>> = suspendCoroutine { it.resume(Response.Success(shareDao.getAll()) }``` (нет возможности проверить работоспособность). Тогда в ViewModel ```emit(repository.getAll())```.

Comment: да, такой вариант работает (это здорово), однако, при добавлении записи в БД не происходит обновления, т.к. это уже не LiveData, а одиночный запрос и подписка.

Comment: Решил иначе (оставил LiveData в Dao и репозиторий как был, изменил только ViewModel), код добавил к вопросу, можете оставить комментарий по решению?